# Unable to access ftp folder from aws instance using PHP code while connection is fine

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ftp

My Php Code is, which have some error on aws server

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("SERVERIP");
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);        
// login with username and password
ftp_put($conn_id,$target_dir, $_FILES["UploadedImage"]["tmp_name"], FTP_BINARY);
```

Getting below error with when I send request from aws server, Seems like there is some problem to fetch ftp folder

> Status: Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 08:09:16 GMT Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Mar
>   2017 08:09:16 +0000 Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10 ETag: "1490170156" Content-Language: en
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Cache-Control: no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Type: text/html Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Content-Length:
>   68 Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT  Check Internet
>   Connection/Router. Contact Local Administrator

Comment: Check Is it ftp or sftp ?

Comment: it is ftp.........

Comment: Just to be sure: You're trying to upload an image to another server as the HTML-form is on? Because if not, there would be no need to connect to FTP to upload a image.

Comment: are you able to login on ftp programmatically in this code?

Comment: I able to upload from localhost and any other server, Problem with only AWS server

Comment: What does the `ftp_put` return? Does the `ftp_put` issue any PHP warning? What does it mean *"I send request from aws server"*? Where do you get the error form your question? Is that HTTP response? Or what is it?

Comment: check this link http://serverfault.com/questions/338775/phps-ftp-isnt-working-on-amazon-linux-ec2-instance

Answer (score 1):

*You didn't really provide us much information that can be used to identify the problem.*

Anyway, you are using active FTP mode. The active FTP mode hardly works these days due to ubiquitous firewalls and NATs. Particularly the AWS network in NATted. In general, you should always use the passive FTP mode.

For details, see my article on [FTP active and passive modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

In PHP, you switch to the passive mode by calling the [`ftp_pasv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) after the `ftp_connect` (or the `ftp_login`, if you use that).

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("SERVERIP");

$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);        

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions from my comment.